# Upgrading SQL Server 2008 to Visual Studio 2013's version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm developing a project (desktop app) with Visual Studio 2010 (.NET Framework 4 + WPF)and SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows XP.

I upgraded my OS to windows 8.1 and now I am using Visual Studio 2013; it asks me to upgrade the database if I do is it still work on Windows XP if not how to edit it with Visual Studio 2013 without upgrading?

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade your SQL Server version - just don't install the new SQL Server version and keep developing with VS 2013 against SQL Server 2008 Express as before .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010's `Database` Projects have been replaced by `SSDT` Projects in Visual Studio 2013, and you are being asked by Visual Studio to upgrade your Database project to SSDT, not to upgrade the actual Database.

I have recently updated a Solution from VS2010 to VS2013 and have been through the same experience. I am also developing against a SQL Server 2008 (R2) database.

Initially I resisted upgrading my VS project, but changed my mind as it became a hassle. There were no adverse side-effects for me, other than I recall having to drop the new SSDT project from the Solution and add it back.

Your SQL Server database will not be affected by you changing your VS project.